# oracle: decode and subquery select result

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery, decode

I have a oracle query and part of it is calculating some value using DECODE.  For example:

```
SELECT ..., 
      (SELECT DECODE((SELECT 23 FROM DUAL), 
                      0, null,
                     (SELECT 23 FROM DUAL))  
         FROM DUAL) 
  FROM ...
```

Here the value "23" gets calculated at runtime, and it's quite complicated joins - multiple tables, uses `PARTITION BY` etc.  So I want to  avoid executing the same subquery if the value is not "0". Is there any way to write something like this

```
SELECT ..., 
       (SELECT DECODE ((SELECT 23 FROM DUAL) as test, 
                        0, null,
                       test)  
         FROM DUAL) 
  FROM ...
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Will this work for you?
I've just moved the "23" to an inline table with a descriptive alias.

```
select ..., 
  (
   select 
     decode ( 
            computed_value.val, 
            0, null,
            computed_value.val
            )  
   from
     (select 23 as val from dual) computed_value
  )
from
  ...
```

A CASE statement might also add clarity, as in:

```
select
  ...
 ,case when computed_value.val = 0
       then null
       else computed_value.val
       end as my_field
from
  (select 23 as val from dual) computed_value
  ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Or:

```
WITH q AS (
SELECT 23 test, 16 test2 FROM dual
)
SELECT ... 
     , DECODE(q.test, 0, NULL, q.test) value
     , CASE WHEN q.test2 = 0 THEN NULL 
            WHEN q.test2 = 16 THEN 1
            ELSE q.test2
       END another_value
  FROM q, ...
```

Lets you use the query "q" throughout your main select, where ever a subquery is allowed. Called the WITH clause, or Common Table Expression, or Subquery Factoring. Read more about it at [Oracle-Base.com](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/WithClause.php).

Comment: Hi @DCookie, Thanks for your input. I cannot use 'with as' since the subquery is using some values from outer query.

Answer (score 1):

For this particular scenario, you could use the [`NULLIF`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions102.htm#i1001340) function:

```
SELECT ..., 
      (SELECT NULLIF((SELECT 23 FROM DUAL), 0)  
         FROM DUAL) 
  FROM ...
```

The `NULLIF` function returns `NULL` if the two arguments are equal, otherwise it returns the first argument.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the subquery in from clause and do something like below:

```
select conf_key, decode(test, 0, null, test) from (
select conf_key, (select conf_value from config_values where conf_key = 'DOMAINID') as TEST from config_values )
```

Answer (score 0):

Better you would have use CASE statement. since the CASE statement is like a series of IF statements, only using the key word WHEN. A CASE statement is evaluated from top to bottom. If a condition is true, then corresponding THEN clause is executed and execution jumps to the END CASE (short circuit evaluation) clause.